# Error in Phrasal System Training

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

I'm a newbie to Stanford phrasal and I'm using phrasal for my research. I'm facing the following error after executing the command `phrasal.sh fr-en.vars 1-6 fr-en.ini baseline` at terminal.

```
===========================
Phrasal training and tuning 
===========================

Loading local parameters from fr-en.vars
System name: baseline
Executing steps: 1-6
Phrasal home:
Running Step 1 -- Extract phrases from dev set
Running Step 2 -- Run tuning
Running Step 3 -- Extract phrases from test set
Running Step 4 -- Decode test set
Running Step 5 -- Output results file
Error: Could not find or load main class #edu.stanford.nlp.mt.metrics.BLEUMetric
Running Step 6 -- Generate a learning curve from an online run
ls: cannot access /home/neotenicity/refs/newstest2012/ref*: No such file or directory
```

Previously I did that, the files `phrase-extract.gz` and `lo-hier.msd2-bidirectional-fe.gz` are not located in the folder `newstest2011.tables` and `newstest2012.tables`. Then, I copied the files `dev12tune.phrase-table.gz` and `dev12tune.lo-hier.msd2-bidirectional-fe.gz` from `phrasal/test-resources/inputs` and pasted them into ".tables" folders and renamed it. Is this a correct way?

Please give me a solution.

Comment: error clearly says that the file or directory doesn't exist..make sure that you have a valid path(`/home/neotenicity/refs/newstest2012/`). try to access it throught your explorer and rerun your command..

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lucky.But in the above error you mentioned is created by the step 5 which is
"Error: Could not find or load main class #edu.stanford.nlp.mt.metrics.BLEUMetric".
If you able to slove the step 5 then automatically step 6 can solved.

Comment: have you added the phrasal Home directory to your PATH? if not you might want to add this `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/phrasal/scripts` and try this installation steps..https://github.com/stanfordnlp/phrasal#installation

Comment: run `phrasal.sh` in your terminal..if you have set the PATH properly it would show up the (six)step definitions..

Comment: yes i add the path and `phrasal.sh` is showing the six steps definition.but this error is came after the six steps definition

Comment: pls post your code and configurations..its hard to help without knowing your code..or try to explain what are the steps you have followed that got you this error..